# How to display External url from Cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

HI i am new in angular js now i am doing a app using cordova ionic frame work, in that i need to display external url:

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").src = 'http://barwatv.fuegodigital.com/tv-955';

<iframe id="myFrame" width="100%" height={{iframeHeight}}>
```

I am using this code for displaying that url every thing is working fine but the problem is when a video come in that external url it is not playing?

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").src = 'http://barwatv.fuegodigital.com/tv-955';

<iframe id="myFrame" width="100%" height={{iframeHeight}}>
```

Comment: Please refer https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/01/embed-video-ios-android-ionicframework-app/

Comment: Thanks dude it works . is there any way to play the video on loading ?i need to play the video without clicking the play button.